# How to pass variable in sqlite query while fetching data in iphone application

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql, sqlite

I am getting data from sqlite table and i want to pass the variable so that if sub_Catgeory is Equal to that variable then it should fetch records.

```
  const char *sql = "select * from category where sub_Category=appDelegate.sub_Category";
```

And same if without using appDelegate.Sub_Category variable then it works fine

```
  const char *sql = "select * from category where sub_Category='Glucagon'";
```

My complete code

```
   + (void) getInitialData:(NSString *)dbPath {

     MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

     if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        //const char *sql = "select * from category where sub_Category='Glucagon'";

       NSLog(@"Sub Category is %@",appDelegate.subCategory);

       const char *sql = "select * from category where sub_Category='appDelegate. subcategory'";

       sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
       if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK {

         while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
            coffeeObj.category=sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt,1);
            coffeeObj.sub_Category = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
            coffeeObj.content_Type = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)];
            coffeeObj.content_Title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,4)];

            coffeeObj.publisher = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 5)];
            coffeeObj.content_Description = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 6)];
            coffeeObj.content_Id = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 7)];
            coffeeObj.content_Source = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 8)];

            int count=[appDelegate.arrayOneC count];

            NSLog(@"count is beofore getting values %d",count);

            [appDelegate.arrayOneC addObject:coffeeObj];

            int countone=[appDelegate.arrayOneC count];

            NSLog(@"count is after getting values %d",countone);

            [coffeeObj release];
        }
    }
}
else
    sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
}
```

Comment: Check updated code. This is not good practice to ask all to edit in your code. How will you learn than ?

Comment: Replace it by :: NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from category where sub_Category = \"%@\"", appDelegate.subCategory];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

1st way.

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from category where sub_Category='%@'", appDelegate.subCategory];
const char *sqlQuery = [queryString UTF8String];

     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlQuery, -1, &selectStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
                while (sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW){
    //Fetching your data logic
    }
}
```

2nd way.

```
const char *sqlStatement = "select * from category where sub_Category=?";

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &selectStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
    sqlite3_bind_text(selectStmt, 1, [appDelegate.subCategory  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    while(sqlite3_step(selectStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
    {
            //Process data
    }
}
```

Thanks  HarshIT, rmaddy and  Jennis.

Comment: this giving error sub_Catgory not a structure or union

Comment: i have added my code can you please edit in my code and why this error is coming

Comment: Are you sure sub_Category variable declare is in your AppDelegate class. First Check the scope of sub_Category variable. If sub_Category has value then i'm 101% sure this code work absolutely error free.

Comment: sub_catgory has values

Comment: Show me your appDelegate variable declaration.

Comment: i am NSLog it shows values  NSString*subCategory;
 
 

 
 
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString*subCategory;

Comment: How you synthesis it? What so you not feel there is difference between subCategory and sub_Category? See my updated code.

Comment: yes i have synthesize it

Comment: Show you synthesize code.

Comment: The answer by Jennis is much better. Don't use `stringWithFormat` to create queries. Use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` calls to properly bind values to the query. It is much safer and less error prone.

Comment: sqlite3_bind_text ,is better way than using stringWithFormat: ,i prefer to bind rather than formatting in such a way.

Comment: Ok i edit my question with two scenario.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like,

Assuming you have declared `static sqlite3_stmt *selectStmt = nil;` some where

```
const char *sqlStatement = "select * from category where sub_Category=?";

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &selectStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
    sqlite3_bind_text(selectStmt, 1, [appDelegate.sub_Category  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    while(sqlite3_step(selectStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
    {
            //Process data
    }
}

//Reset the select statement.
sqlite3_reset(selectStmt);
selectStmt = nil;
```

Its known as binding values to prepared statements. [Check here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) for more detailed information.

***EDIT -- See below your function edited.***

```
+(void)getInitialData:(NSString *)dbPath
{
    MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Sub Category is %@",appDelegate.subCategory);
        const char *sql = "select * from category where sub_Category=?";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(selectStmt, 1, [appDelegate.sub_Category  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                coffeeObj.category=sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt,1);
                coffeeObj.sub_Category = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
                coffeeObj.content_Type = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)];
                coffeeObj.content_Title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,4)];
                coffeeObj.publisher = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 5)];
                coffeeObj.content_Description = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 6)];
                coffeeObj.content_Id = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 7)];
                coffeeObj.content_Source = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 8)];
                int count=[appDelegate.arrayOneC count];
                NSLog(@"count is beofore getting values %d",count);
                [appDelegate.arrayOneC addObject:coffeeObj];
                int countone=[appDelegate.arrayOneC count];
                NSLog(@"count is after getting values %d",countone);
                [coffeeObj release];
            }
        }
    }
    else
        sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: where to give variable you have just given ?

Comment: can you please edit in my code i am addding my code

Comment: it is giving error sub_Catgory is not a structure or union

Comment: One thing you should add to this code is a call to `sqlite_finalize` for the statement.

Answer (score 3):

Try this ::

```
NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from category where sub_Category = \"%@\"", appDelegate.subCategory];

const char *sql = [selectSQL UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *searchStatement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbName, sql, -1, &searchStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(searchStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {

    }
}
sqlite3_finalize(searchStatement);
```

Hope, it'll help you.

Thanks.